# Reshaping count-summarised data into long form in R

Tags: r

Embarrassingly basic question, but if you don't know..  I need to reshape a data.frame of count summarised data into what it would've looked like before being summarised.  This is essentially the reverse of `{plyr} count()` e.g.

```
> (d = data.frame(value=c(1,1,1,2,3,3), cat=c('A','A','A','A','B','B')))
  value cat
1     1   A
2     1   A
3     1   A
4     2   A
5     3   B
6     3   B
> (summry = plyr::count(d))
  value cat freq
1     1   A    3
2     2   A    1
3     3   B    2
```

If you start with `summry` what is the quickest way back to `d`?  Unless I'm mistaken (very possible), `{Reshape2}` doesn't do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `rep`:

```
summry[rep(rownames(summry), summry$freq), c("value", "cat")]
#     value cat
# 1       1   A
# 1.1     1   A
# 1.2     1   A
# 2       2   A
# 3       3   B
# 3.1     3   B
```

A variation of this approach can be found in [`expandRows`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/expandRows.R) from [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun). If you had that loaded, you would be able to simply do:

```
expandRows(summry, "freq")
```

Comment: I didn't know `rep` accepts a vector, many thanks!

Comment: `SOfun` looks jolly useful btw

Comment: +1 for the SOfun reference !

Comment: @geotheory, Glad to help, and have fun with the package :-)

Comment: @Henk, thanks. I hope you find something useful in there!

Answer (score 1):

There is a good table to dataframe function on the [R cookbook website](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_between_data_frames_and_contingency_tables/) that you can modify slightly.  The only modifications were changing 'Freq' -> 'freq' (to be consistent with `plyr::count`) and making sure the rownames were reset as increasing integers.

```
expand.dft <- function(x, na.strings = "NA", as.is = FALSE, dec = ".") {
  # Take each row in the source data frame table and replicate it
  # using the Freq value
  DF <- sapply(1:nrow(x), 
               function(i) x[rep(i, each = x$freq[i]), ],
               simplify = FALSE)

  # Take the above list and rbind it to create a single DF
  # Also subset the result to eliminate the Freq column
  DF <- subset(do.call("rbind", DF), select = -freq)

  # Now apply type.convert to the character coerced factor columns  
  # to facilitate data type selection for each column 
  for (i in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    DF[[i]] <- type.convert(as.character(DF[[i]]),
                            na.strings = na.strings,
                            as.is = as.is, dec = dec)
  }
  row.names(DF) <- seq(nrow(DF))
  DF
}

expand.dft(summry)

  value cat
1     1   A
2     1   A
3     1   A
4     2   A
5     3   B
6     3   B
```